# CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

Here I'm trying to run this code but i am getting CORS error when integrated with angular.
this is my source code
**Settings.py file**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'webapp',
'rest_framework',
'knox',
'django_rest_passwordreset',
'corsheaders',
  ]
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 ]
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

I'm adding all of these but I'm getting same error while running.
Tell me the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because, you need to add **Allowed header**s. Because when you're calling api, by default **Content-Type** will be added. Add this at the end.

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ('Authorization', 'Content-Type', 'Cache-Control', 'X-Requested-With')
```

Comment: I'm added this line but getting same CORS error. Is there any changes in angular ?

Comment: Yeah u need to check in angular side. check this https://www.techiediaries.com/fix-cors-with-angular-cli-proxy-configuration/